# List of globals in Typescript

Tags: typescript, global

Is it possible to configure the Typescript compiler to recognize certain symbols as global variables?

For example, right now you can tell the compiler that a symbol exists in your code with:

```
declare var MY_GLOBAL: number;
```

But if you need to use this variable in many different files, it would be better if you could let Typescript know about it in `tsconfig.json` so you wouldn't have to have this line in every single file that uses this variable. Is this possible?

Comment: Is it Angular2 app? Then you can create shared service, make your variable a part of it and access from different components. If not - `typings` might help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is already the behavior in files which are not modules (those which lack top-level `import`s or `export`s). The easiest thing to do is to make a non-module file and put the declaration there. But if your file is a module and you want to declare something in the global scope, and you are using TypeScript 2.0 or later, you can use `declare global`:

```
declare global {
    var MY_GLOBAL: number;
}
```